# Unmarshaling XML in Go with Conflicting Element Names

Tags: xml, encoding, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have the following XML, externally defined and outside of my organization's control:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <zip>zip</zip>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <zap>zap</zap>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

I am using these structs:

```
type Foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"foo"`
    Bar1    Bar1
    Bar2    Bar2
}

type Bar1 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"bar"`
    Zip     string   `xml:"zip"`
}

type Bar2 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"bar"`
    Zap     string   `xml:"zap"`
}
```

Because of the conflicting 'bar' name, nothing gets unmarshaled. How can I populate the Bar1 and Bar2 structs?

This is what I have: https://play.golang.org/p/D2IRLojcTB

This is the result I want: https://play.golang.org/p/Ytrbzzy9Ok

In the second one, I have updated the second 'bar' to be 'bar1,' and it all works. I'd rather come up with a cleaner solution that modifying the incoming XML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `encoding/xml` package won't be able to do exactly what you want, since it makes the decision over which field of `Foo` to decode into when it encounters the `<bar>` element, rather than when processing children of that element.  Your struct definitions make this decision ambiguous, as the error from `xml.Unmarshal` indicates:

> main.Foo field "Bar1" with tag "" conflicts with field "Bar2" with tag ""

Here are two alternatives that will work though:

**1. Use one `Bar` struct to cover both branches**

If you modify your types to read as:

```
type Foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"foo"`
    Bars    []Bar    `xml:"bar"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Zip string `xml:"zip"`
    Zap string `xml:"zap"`
}
```

You will now get a slice that represents all the `<bar>` elements.  You can tell whether the element had a `<zip>` or `<zap>` element by checking whether the corresponding fields are non-empty.

You can try out this version here: https://play.golang.org/p/kguPCYmKX0

**2. Use child selectors**

If you are only interested in a single child element of `<bar>` in each branch, then you might not need a struct to represent that element at all.  For example, you could decode into the following type:

```
type Foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"foo"`
    Zip     string   `xml:"bar>zip"`
    Zap     string   `xml:"bar>zap"`
}
```

Now the children of the `<bar>` elements will be decoded directly into members of the `Foo` struct.  Note that with this option you won't be able to distinguish your chosen input from e.g.

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <zip>zip</zip>
    <zap>zap</zap>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

If that will cause problems, then you should pick the first solution.

You can try out this version here: https://play.golang.org/p/fAE_HSrv4y

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for such a detailed response. I will likely go with the 1st option, because the zip and zap are much more nested in reality.

You mention it won't be possible with encoding/xml. Are there any built-in libraries that are maybe slightly more complex, but allow for the ambiguity?

Comment: You might be able to handle some cases by implementing the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface to implement custom decoding for a type, but that is non-trivial.  It might be simpler to use option (1) above, and then copy the data to your target data structure.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Go and XML so I will stick with option (1) :)